# Why does Solving system of quadratic equations gives extra roots?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, quadratics

Consider these system of Equations
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x^2+4x+4=0\\\\
x^2+5x+6=0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

For solving them
We have

Method 1-

Subtract both equations

So
$-x-2=0$

Hence,
$x=-2$

Method-2

Add both equations

$2x^2+9x+10=0$

After applying quadratic formula, we get

$x=-2$ or $x=-5/2$. But only $x=-2$ satisfies the system of equation.

Why is the $-5/2$ not satisfying the system of equations, what is intuition behind the error in method 2?

Comment: Edited to correct MathJax, please refer to corrections and adapt in the future, you have just missed something quite tiny to be fair. On your question : If $a$ is a root of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ then it's a root of $(p-q)(x)$, $(p+q)(x)$ and so on. But these polynomials could have other roots, which have nothing to do with $p$ or $q$.

Comment: Both methods are one way implications which are not reversible. Method 1, for example, means that if a common root exists, then it must be $x=-2$, but it does not prove that $x=-2$ is in fact a root. Try to apply method 1 to the system $x+3=0, 2x+1=0$ for example.

Comment: Both methods are fine but to get an equivalence you need to keep one of the initial equations or another composition of these (keeping the difference **and** the sum is fine since you could recompose both initial equations!)

Comment: @Teresa Lisbon,the what actually happens with p(x) and q(x),when the term x² is eliminated from both equations,and linear equation is obtained,why don't we get 2 results from here,I know that linear equation can only have one solution,but where did that extra root go?

Comment: @dxiv,can you please elaborate what does it mean one way implication,isn't this method of gauss elimination or handling system of equations always correct?please correct me if I am understanding it wrong

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi When you perform $p(x)-q(x)$, it is true that IF $a$ is a common root of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$, then it is also a root of $(p-q)(x)$, and of $(p+q)(x)$ , and of $(2p+3q)(x)$ and so on. But the *opposite* is not true : if I now take *any* root of $(p-q)(x)$, it is *not* necessary that it must have been a common root of $p(x)$ and $q(x)$. What is the reason? Well, think about numbers : $1$ is not a multiple of $3$ and $2$ is not a multiple of $3$, but $1+2 = 3$ is a multiple of $3$. So $1+2$, or $1-2$ , can only share some multiplicative property that both $1$ and $2$ share commonly

Comment: The reason why this holds for numbers is because if $a$ and $b$ are two numbers, then all we can say about the divisors of $a+b$ for *sure*, is that IF $a,b$ share a divisor then this number is also a divisor of $a+b$. BUT we can't discuss factors of $a+b$ that *don't* come from either $a$ or $b$ ( to do this, one will have to discuss remainders, which is out of the present context).

Comment: @TeresaLisbon,was that comment meant to say that consider example 4 and 2,they share common factor 2 so 2 will also divide 4+2 i.e 2 will also divide 2(2+1)?correct me if I am not handling it the way you told

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi Exactly : but you can't predict, for example that $4+2$ is a multiple of $3$, *without* dividing $4$ by $2$, and then $2$ by $2$, and then proceeding to add them and check that it is a multiple of $3$ (or taking the remainder when $4$ is divided by $3$, the remainder when $2$ is divided by $3$, and adding them up). In other words, until you investigate further, you will not know that $3$ has anything multiplicative to do with $4+2$.

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi A one way implication is of the form $A \implies B$, as opposed to an equivalence $A \iff B$. Again, try to apply your method(s) to the simpler system $x+3=0, 2x+1=0$ and it will become apparent where the problem is. You can subtract the equations and get $-x+2=0$, but this does not mean you found the solution $x=2$. What it means is that you reduced the system to another system of two equations $x+3=0, -x+2=0$ (which happens to have no solutions).

Comment: @dxiv,thanks a lot,sincerely,I was confused regarding the systems,now I know,whenever we form new equations out of old one,we can't consider the only new derived equation to get the answer,all of the equations hence derived must also satisfy,and for this questions,it seems very intuitive if we take common solution of x+2=0 and 2x^2+9x+10=0,thanks,and too,is that correct?one way implication means that "if a implies b then b does not necessarily imply a"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason, that method 2 can lead to an extraneous solution, is that you replaced two equations by a single equation and in that you lost some information.

You had two equations:
\begin{align*}
x^2+4x+4&=0\\\\
x^2+5x+6&=0
\end{align*}

You replaced them by their sum:
$$2x^2+9x+10=0.\tag{1}$$

But from the equation $(1)$ you cannot deduce the original two equations.

---

For example, if you used both the sum and one of the original equations
\begin{align*}
x^2+4x+4&=0\\\\
2x^2+9x+10&=0
\end{align*}
you would get an equivalent system of equations - since from these two equations you can derive the original equations. (By subtracting the first one from the second one.)

---

Naturally, simply replacing system of two equations can lead to an extraneous solution two. It wasn't the case here - but it can happen for various other systems of equations.

Still, I would not call this an error - one sholud keep in mind that if we're change an equation (or a system) to a new one which is not equivalent to the original one (but is consequence of the original one) there might be more solutions.
So one should check (whenever using non-equivalent transformations) whether there aren't extraneous solutions.

Comment: are you suggesting that those two equation represent specific necessity that is missing in third combined form,example a+b=c,a+2b=3c,these two equations imply two different necessities to be completed,but thier addition 2a+3b=4c does not state anything about the conditions on a+b and a+2b,the second equation might suggest a+2b=c and a+b=3c ,have I got it correct?

Comment: @DheerajGujrathi This is exactly the idea I was trying to get across. 
Every solution of the system a+b=c, a+2b=3c is a solution 2a+3b=4c but not vice-versa.
But if you compare the systems a+b=c, a+2b=3c and 2a+3b=4c, b=2c; these systems are equivalent and they have exactly the same solutions.
I would suggest that if we want to discuss this further, we can try to continue [in this chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2023/9/10) - so that we do not create a long comment thread here.

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

You can factor both polynomials according to your preferred method in order to obtain:

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
x^{2} + 4x + 4 = 0\\\\
x^{2} + 5x + 6 = 0
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
(x+2)^{2} = 0\\\\
(x+2)(x+3) = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: ,yes,I can,thanks,but one more question,what if instead of 4x it was written ax,and we were told to find a such that it both polynomials share a common factor?we can't factor them out?

Comment: If you had an unknown parameter $a$, you could solve the corresponding quadratic equation and compare the roots to those related to the second equation. In this way, you could find its value.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your title question:

> Why does Solving system of quadratic equations gives extra roots?

This is because any quadratic equation can have at most two solutions, so a system of quadratic equations may at most two solutions in common between the two quadratic equations.

Specifically, you have two quadratic equations, and they share one solution, up to multiplicity, and so you have 3 extraneous roots.

If they have more than one solution in common, they'd necessarily be scalar multiples of one another.

Answer (score 1):

We could also describe the difference in your two approaches in this way.  You began with the system $ \ p(x) \ = \ x^2   + 4x + 4 \ = \ 0 \ , \ q(x) \ = \ x^2 + 5x + 6  \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  When you subtract  one equation from the other, you have $ \ p(x) - q(x) \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ which is equivalent to the equation we would set up for finding intersections of the curves represented by these functions, $ \ p(x) \ = \ q(x) \ \ . $  You found the single solution $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ \   $ from $ \ -x - 2 \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ which is correct.  It so happens for this system that this *also* locates a common factor of $ \ p(x) \ $ and $ \ q(x) \ $ because both functions are equal to zero at $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ \ , $ but this method would be correct to use in any case (as we'll show shortly for a different system).

[image]

When you *add* the two equations, as you did in your second calculation, you are now solving $ \ p(x) + q(x) \ = \ 0 \ \rightarrow \ p(x) \ = \ -q(x) \ \ , $ which is no longer the original problem.  Here, it  really is  **only** because both $ \ p(x) \ $ and $ \ q(x) \ $ are equal to zero at $ \ x \ = \ -2 \ $ that this appears as a solution to $ \ 2x^2 + 9x + 10 \ = \ (2x + 5 )·(x + 2) \ = \ 0 \ \ , $ since $ \ (x + 2)·(x + 2) \ + \ (x + 2)·(x + 3) $
$ = \ (x + 2)·[ \ (x + 2) + (x + 3) \ ] \ \ . $  Other systems may not produce any solutions at all by adding the equations.

[image]

If we take, for example, the system $ \ p(x) \ = \ x^2 - 5x + 6  \ = \ ( x - 2)·(x - 3) \ = \ 0 \ , $
$ q(x) \ = \ x^2   + 7x + 10 \ = \ (x + 2)·(x + 5) \ =  0 \ \ , $ the two polynomials have no factors in common, but surely must intersect since they both "open upward".  We find $ \ p(x) \ = \ q(x) $ $ \Rightarrow \ p(x) - q(x) \ = \ -12x - 4 \ = \ 0 \ \Rightarrow \ x \ = \ -\frac13 \ \ , $ a solution which is not suggested immediately by any of the polynomial factors.  [Indeed, we could have chosen two "upward-opening" parabolas represented by polynomials which cannot be factored using real numbers and would still be able to find the intersection(s).]

[image]

On the other hand, $ \ p(x) + q(x) \ = \ 2x^2 + 2x + 16 \ \ $ has no real zeroes (or $ \ p(x) \ = \ -q(x) \ $ has no real-number solutions); we see that the function curves do not intersect.  So adding the equations together in this system provides no information about the solutions of the original system of equations.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> $x^2+4x+4=0 \implies (x+2)^2=0$ Similarly factorise the other polynomial and see which value of $x$ is common in them

For other part of question your method didn't gave the right answer because you must remember $(a-b)x,(a+b)x$ can have roots other than $a$ and $b$